# 10 members of the sales staff have [ already/early] exceeded their quotas

Tags: word-usage

I thought that (already ) is right but i just want to know why the word is not right? 
Would you please tell me the reason?

Comment: Either *Ten members of the sales staff have already exceeded their quotas* or *Ten members of the sales staff have exceeded their quotas early.*

Comment: Who or what has told you that *already* is not right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **early** can not be placed in that **specific position** in the sentence. If you chose to use **early**, it would need to be placed at the **end** of the sentence.

> 10 members of the sales staff have exceeded their quotas **early**.

(Side note: we don't generally use digits to start a sentence, unless it's unavoidable. Here, we should just opt for spelling the word "Ten")

There is no concrete rule to decide this, early can be an adverb, and generally adverbs can be adjacent to the verbs they modify, but this one can't. Here is an interesting summary of [types of adverbs and their possible placements](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml).